# SharedViewModel between the scope of a fragment

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have two fragment that should share a viemodel

```
class FragmentA(): Fragment() {
  val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider.(need_a_shared_context)....//not the activity context
}

class FragmentB(): Fragment() {
val sharedViewModel = ViewModelProvider.(need_a_shared_context).... //not the activity context
}
```

now, inside each fragment I need to access a shared viewmodel but not a sharedviewmodel hosted by the activity containing these fragments, because I'm working with Firebase and I have a listener sending data to my app.

So, If I attach the viewmodel to the activity lifecycle, I can share data between these two, but, it will be also listening for data when I'm not in `FragmentA()` or `FragmentB()`

Is there a way to scope the creation of this sharedviewmodel when I'm only at FragmentA() or FragmentB() ?

### Edit

Since I'm using NavigationComponents, when I navigate from `FragmentA()` to `FragmentB()` , fragment A dies, so , If I create there my sharedviewmodel, it will die when I access `FragmentB()` and `FragmentB()` will generate a new instance of the viewmodel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is kinda too wide.

Why don't u want the activity to host the viewmodel? If you dont want your listeners to be notified while not actually displaying the UI, you can remove it [listeners]. I do not know exactly about Realtime Database (sure it has same features), but Firestore's `addSnapshotListener` methods return `ListenerRegistration` object, which has a `remove()` method to remove the listener, so you are not notified about the document updates and thus not charged for it.

You can host the `ViewModel` by any component you want, but I would even consider using Object for it, so every instance of your `ViewModel` gets the same singleton, which stores the cached value and exposes it in the form of `LiveData` to your observers, but actually starts and stops observing the Firebase node (and updating the `LiveData` your fragments observe) only after specific methods get called - `onStartObserving()`/`onStopObserving`, which can be called from your fragments' `onStart()` & `onStop()`